# 1 minute gif size and load speed

Tags: load, gif, filesize

[Test http://www.raapwerk.nl/zooi/03-wie-wij-zijn_1.gif](http://www.raapwerk.nl/zooi/03-wie-wij-zijn_1.gif)

^ This is a (sped up) test for a gif for a site I'm working on (it only plays when you follow the link). Eventually it should be a one minute long gif with about 12 frames per second. The four portraits interact with each other, so they have to play at exactly the same time.

Now, the problem is that the gif's file-size is huge (about 8 MB), and now I'm trying to figure out a way to make it loadable (preferably by decreasing the file size). Is there a way, or should I abandon gif's altogether and usa a different file-format/technique?

Comment: If it's a minute of video then why don't you go for video? You can stream that plus it will probably be smaller than the gif.

Comment: Do you mean html5 video? It has to loop infinitely. Is that also possible?

Comment: Yes that should be possible, only "drawback" would be that you cannot autoplay the video on mobile devices (this will require user interaction), but I guess you'll have a hard time with animated gifs on mobile too.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also give us a direction to look at concerning cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: `<video>` has pretty solid support by now: http://caniuse.com/#search=video , also see http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody